# Firebase Hosting: Connect with own AWS backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, ssl, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to connect my firebase hosted app with my backend hosted in an aws ec2 instance? Is it possible to use the ssl certificate from firebase? Or can I use the certificate from aws Certificate Manager?

Answer (score 6):

You can call out to your own hosted backend via XHR (using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)) or you can connect your Firebase Hosting site to a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) which would then be able to proxy to your ec2 instance. You cannot directly connect Firebase Hosting with AWS.

The certificate used for Firebase Hosting cannot be reused for other purposes, and you cannot upload your own certificate (from e.g. Certificate Manager) into Firebase Hosting.

Comment: It would the connection from my firebase website to my backend be encrypted if I would use one of these options?

Comment: You would have to make sure your ec2 instance was serving HTTPS by using a certificate from e.g. Amazon Certificate Manager.

Comment: Regarding the proxy option: Does it mean I have to write a proxy for each REST method of my backend?

Comment: You could design a proxy such that you don't -- your proxy is just going to be arbitrary Node.js code, so you can do pretty much whatever you like!