# Front End Static website on Firebase Hosting has XmlHttpRequest error talking to my Elastic Beanstalk Back End

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, firebase-hosting

I have a static website on Firebase hosting. However, it does not hit the endpoints when it talks to my Asp.net Core backend hosted on Elastic Beanstalk.

All I can see from the browser is this:

[image]

So it is pretty hard to tell the reason but does this sound like CORS?

It works fine from localhost (E.G when I run the static web app from vscode, but still pointing to my elastic beanstalk server, it successfully talks to it). I have made the Asp.net Core back end allow all CORS origins, headers, and methods:

```
app.UseCors(options =>
{
    options.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
});
```

So why am I getting CORS errors (I think) when hitting its endpoints?

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47315041/3935156) is about this and says it is a CORS issue, and it says you can't get your firebase hosting static app to talk to your AWS elastic beanstalk server, but I don't know where to go from that answer. This part of his answer sounds the easiest as I don't want to write node.js code for this:

> You can call out to your own hosted backend via XHR (using CORS)

What does this entail? I feel like I am already doing that just by making an http request to my back end. Can someone please enlighten a complete noob about the issue and the solution?

EDIT btw I just had an idea, my back end app allows only port 5002:

```
 webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:5002");
```

So is this the problem, and can I make Firebase use port 5002? Ahh, nah, I have added 5002 to the end of the url from the front end http request so I think this is not the issue.

Maybe I need to configure a certificate for my back end which I have not done, as my front end  was always hosted with an http url and firebase hosting has made it https?

I have also deployed the static web app to AWS S3; the url is http and it manages to talk to my elastic beanstalk server fine. However, my app needs location permission from the web browser, and the browser is disabling it when it is hosted on AWS S3, saying it doesn't trust it. So I think I must need to host on https (and FB Hosting is very fast to set that up).

Answer (score 0):

[This explains it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content). I need my elastic beanstalk endpoint to be https for https browsers to trust my content.

My beanstalk environment is a single server instance so I think I can [do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html):

Add .ebextensions/https-instance-securitygroup.config to the root of my asp.net project:

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

And redeploy. Fingers crossed.